# NumberFormat VBA With User-Defined Data

Tags: vba, excel, number-formatting, userform, user-data

I am working on a workbook that has a set number of template calculations that are used multiple times across the scope of the copied workbook. A form object was created where the user is to enter an identifier for each calculation set that meets a specific format. It generally follows "aaa-##0.00" where the 'aaa' is a string of 1 to 3 letters. The form then has a combo box that is cleared and populated on activation that contains the 258, customer-provided text possibilities (to reduce probable user error) with a text box adjacent to it for entering the digits. When the "execute" button is clicked, it identifies the selected calculations required from the user form, copies the template worksheet(s) to the end of the workbook, and populates the identifier information at the bottom of a list on the Contents page. Here is the relevant code:

```
Dim prefix As String
Dim LocMP As Double

'The digits are entered in txtLocMP
LocMP = Val(txtLocMP.Value)

'mpPrefixLst is the combo box, with 'prefix' being the desired custom format
prefix = mpPrefixLst.Text & "-#0.00"
```

When debugging, the values stored in 'LocMP' and 'prefix' appear satisfactory with LocMP being a number and 'prefix' being the desired format string. From here, I've tried a couple different options. The first,

```
With Contents
'Contents is type WorkSheet, locCount is the number of entries in Contents
'including the offset for the header
   .Unprotect
          'Other unrelated functions
   .Range("C" & locCount).Value = Format(LocMP, prefix)
          'Other unrelated functions
   .Protect
End With
```

The second,

```
With Contents
          'Other unrelated functions
   With .Range("C" & locCount)
      .Value = LocMP
      .NumberFormat = prefix
   End With
          'Other unrelated functions
End With
```

Neither of these options, though they both make sense to me, produce the desired results. For example, if the provided text for 'mpPrefixLst' is "SFE" then my 'prefix' value shows it is equal to "SFE-#0.00" which is exactly as expected. When the value of 555.44 is entered for LocMP the result in the changed cell is "36FE-#0.00" when the desired result would be "SFE-555.44"! I have searched on this site (and others) for even an approximate solution I could make fit, and the MSDN website is no help at all. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: As I said in my edit, add a backslash between each literal character. http://i.imgur.com/FFRZr5G.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a backslash between each character:

```
Sub Test()
Cells(1, 1).NumberFormat = GetFixedPrefix("SAE-") & "#0.00"
End Sub

Function GetFixedPrefix(prefix as String) as String
Dim x, fixedPrefix
fixedPrefix = ""
For x = 1 to Len(prefix)
    fixedPrefix = fixedPrefix & "\" & Mid(prefix,x,1)
Next x
GetFixedPrefix = fixedPrefix
End Function
```

This makes your NumberFormat = `\S\F\E\-#0.00` which should display correctly:

[image]

[Read More Here](http://www.globaliconnect.com/excel/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=121:custom-number-formats-date-a-time-formats-in-excel-a-vba-numberformat-property&catid=79&Itemid=475)

> Backslash. Any character appearing after backslash `\` will display as a literal, even though it may be reserved as an operator (say, `%`). The number 0.75 with the format code `#.00%` will format to `75.00%`, but with the format code `#.00\%` it will format to `.75%`, ie. format code will not use `%` as operator but as a literal.

Comment: It works! I wonder why it was not being viewed as a text literal from the beginning?

Comment: My guess is this: `E- followed by atleast one "0" character (in format code), displays the number in scientific notation`

Comment: Hmm...I'll have to whittle on that a bit.